# setting up Google Campaign links with Magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento, google-analytics

I'm attempting to set up a Google campaign link to help a client get a more clear view of their print ads.

We have a link: 
mydomain.com/short

I'm forwarding(301 redirect) to: 
mydomain.com/long-google-campaign-link

For some reason it isn't registering as a campaign click in Google. I've tried visiting both the short link and the full link. I suspect this has something to do with how the Magento default .htaccess file redirects traffic.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would that register as campaign click ? You need campaign (utm) parameters, or you have to set the source/medium/campaign info on the landingpage via calls to the ga set method.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Sorry Eike Pierstorff, something came up and I was unable to reply. The link has the campaign parameters. that's what I was trying to imply with: mydomain.com/long-google-campaign-link.